# What are SQL Service reporting service expression?

Tags: reporting-services

I am confused what these expressions are made out of ? i mean is that VB.NET/ VB Script/ Something else with just VB syntax ?

Comment: What is the cannonical name for these expressions?  "Reporting Expressions" seems to be based on the [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx)

Comment: i guess SSRS expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are written with VB.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345242.aspx

Comment: Does that mean that i can consume .NET API into SSRS expressions ?

Comment: a quote from their site

"
Expressions begin with an equal (=) and are written in Microsoft Visual Basic. Expressions can include a combination of constants, operators, and references to built-in values (fields, collections, and functions), and to external or custom code.
"